# How to write onclick action for statically created radio buttons in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android quiz application. In my screen I am displaying a question and options(4 radio buttons statically) with next button. i.e when next button is clicked again 
next question with its options will be displayed. Actually i have a string

```
 str = |ques1@opid1@option1@opid2@option2@opid3@option3@opid4@opotion4|ques2@opid1@option1@opid2@option2@opid3@option3@opid4@opotion4|ques3@opid1@option1@opid2@option2@opid3@option3@opid4@opotion4
```

Now I splitted the str array with "|" and and stored the data into str1.
So,

str1[1] = ques1@opid1@option1@opid2@option2@opid3@option3@opid4
          str1[2] = ques2@opid1@option1@opid2@option2@opid3@option3@opid4
          .........

```
Now again I splitted the str1 array with "@" and stored the data in str2.
So,

 str2[0] = ques1
          str2[1] = opid1
    str2[2] = option1
    str2[3] = opid2
    str2[4] = option2
    str2[5] = opid3
    str2[6] = option3
    str2[7] = opid4
    str2[8] = option4

So after getting these values i am setting it to 
tv.setText(str2[0]);
answer1.setText(str2[2]);
answer2.setText(str2[4]);
answer3.setText(str2[6]);
answer4.setText(str2[8]);
```

Then in next button click action, I wrote the following code.

```
int i = 1;
public void next(View v) {

    if (i < str1.length - 1) {
        i++;
        str3 = str1[i].trim().split("[@]");             
        tv.setText(str3[0]);            
        answers.check(-1);
        answer1.setText(str3[2]);
        answer2.setText(str3[4]);
        answer3.setText(str3[6]);
        answer4.setText(str3[8]);       
    }
```

Now till here everything is fine. My next requirement is to get the selected option value and store it in an array. Also I need to set the option id value to the radio button
selected and get that id value again. i.e for suppose for the first question I selected 2nd radio button so i want to set that option id as radiobtn.setid(opid2) and want to get that selected radio button id. Since i kept the radio buttons statically I am not getting how to set and get id to radio buttons and how to write onclick action to radio buttons.
I am struggling with this. Please any help will be really thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below

```
if(rd.isChecked()==true) // rd is the radio button
 {
  String selected =rd.getText().toString();// get the radio button text

 }
```

To set the id you can use rd.setId(intvalue) and to get the id rd.getId().

Answer (score 0):

please use like this.

```
    if(arg0==btnnext)
    {
    Log.v(TAG+"onClick", "onClick method call");
    //btnback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if(rboption1.isChecked())
    {
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "option 1 selected");

        check=1;
    }
    else if(rboption2.isChecked())
    {
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "option 2 selected");
        check=2;
    }
    else if(rboption3.isChecked())
    {
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "option 3 selected");
        check=3;
    }

    else if(rboption4.isChecked())
    {
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "option 4 selected");
        check=4;
    }

    else
    {
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "No any option is selected");
        check=0;
    }

    if(Integer.parseInt(answer1)==check)
    {
        correctans++;
        Log.v(TAG+"onClick", "Correct answer are:" + correctans);
    }
    else if(check == 0)
    {
        unattempted++;
        Log.v(TAG+"onClick", "unattempted questions:" + unattempted);

    }
    else 
    {
        incorrectans++;
        Log.v(TAG+"onClick", "Wrong answer are:" + incorrectans);
    }

    atempted= correctans+incorrectans;
    attemptedquestions.setText("Attempted : "+atempted);
    // insert into table where that select the 

    index++;

    if(i++ < (list1.size()-1))
    {
        questionanswerbean=list1.get(i);
        Question=questionanswerbean.getQuestion_text();
        Option1=questionanswerbean.getAnswer_choice_1();
        Option2=questionanswerbean.getAnswer_choice_2();
        Option3=questionanswerbean.getAnswer_choice_3();
        Option4=questionanswerbean.getAnswer_choice_4();
            Log.v(TAG+".Oncraete", "Viewing Question ->" + Question);
            Log.v(TAG+".Oncraete", "Viewing Option1 ->" + Option1);
            Log.v(TAG+".Oncraete", "Viewing Option2 ->" + Option2);
            Log.v(TAG+".Oncraete", "Viewing Option3 ->" + Option3);
            Log.v(TAG+".Oncraete", "Viewing Option4 ->" + Option4);

               if ((Question != null) && !Question.trim().equals("")) {
                    question.setText("Question: " +index +":     " + Question.trim());
                }

                if ((Option1 != null) && !Option1.trim().equals("")) {

                    rboption1.setText(Option1.trim());
                }

                if ((Option2 != null) && !Option2.trim().equals("")) {

                    rboption2.setText(Option2.trim());
                }

                if ((Option3 != null) && !Option3.trim().equals("")) {

                    rboption3.setText(Option3.trim());
                }
                if ((Option4 != null) && !Option4.trim().equals("")) {

                    rboption4.setText(Option4.trim());
                }   

                radiogroup.clearCheck();

            }
```